# Nextcloud won’t run after upgrading Ubuntu Server for ARM devices to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, raspberrypi, arm, nextcloud

I posted this on the Nextcloud forums but didn't get any responses there, so here goes. Nextcloud won’t start after upgrading my Ubuntu server running on RPi to 18.04. When I enter the server URL in the browser, it does seem to connect but then a file save window pops up and the file name populated there is `index.php`.

Here are the Nextcloud specs on my RPi:

Nextcloud version (eg, 12.0.2): 13.0.6.1
Operating system and version (eg, Ubuntu 17.04): 18.04.1
Apache or nginx version (eg, Apache 2.4.25): 2.4.29
PHP version (eg, 7.1): 7.2.10

Comment: The question is too general as is. There are no logs or errors attached. Have you tried troubleshooting https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/13/admin_manual/issues/?

Comment: I think I have this sorted. The answer by `Ravi Shankar` on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them) solved my issue.